# CollectionView Changing Layout Animation Problems On Increasing or Decreasing Frame/Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, collectionview

Is there a way to get rid of the collectionView flashing when changing layout? (i.e to change the frame bigger or smaller). Also i have a problem where the offset keep jumping at the last index :/.

Here is my example project, any help would be great!!! https://github.com/kaayr1m/enlarge-collection-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout animated:NO];
```

by default UICollectionView animates all the CUD(create/update/delete) operations and layout switch as it redraws the layout. If you want to add your own animation/transition views you can use -

```
(UICollectionViewTransitionLayout *)collectionView:(UICollectionView
*)collectionView transitionLayoutForOldLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)fromLayout newLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)toLayout
```

Comment: Ohh yeah.. sweet that made the animation less flashy. If that makes sense. Thanks!!